# How can I import spring-boot-dependenies pom with gradle 5 and kts?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I was happy to learn that gradle 5 [supports importing poms natively](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) (like scope import in Maven or  `mavenBom()` from the `spring-dependency-management` plugin)

However, when I try to use this in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    idea
    base
    java
}

dependencies {
    compile(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE"))

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

they do not get resolved.

Comment: getting any particular error ??

Comment: Running -q dependencies I just get failed

Comment: any difference when using single quote ??

Comment: single quotes are not accepted by kts

Comment: you are right. Just checked the guide https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: I like to learn, so I am always curious: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Because for some questions are not questions and people should have infinite knowledge and never ask questions.

Comment: Remember that `compile` and `testCompile` should be replaced with `implementation` and `testImplementation` respectively for new Gradle Versions.